# include multidex but still app crashing download from play store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-console-developer

App was running fine android studio but whenever download from play store app crash on android nougat or lower then then i included multidex but still same error

Build Gradle :

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.------.--"
        minSdkVersion 15                    //lowsdk then 20
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true               //enable multiDexEnabled
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

MainActivity:

```
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener  {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

   continue

}
```

[Stack Trace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3GaT.jpg)

Comment: try to update the library to 2.0.1

And remove the MultiDex.install(this)
You dont need this 

 multiDexEnabled true    is enough

Comment: which exception and stacktrace does it crash with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko this is not my solution

Comment: Stack Trace Image uploaded

Comment: Did you figure out this issue?

Comment: yes! problem was that i was not including some on google admob library in my  gradle file that's why app was crashing